# Валидация диапазонов чисел Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Допустим, у меня в бд есть числовые поля value_from и value_to. Там хранятся значение вида value_from 1, value_to 3 первая запись. Вторая value_from 4, value_to 9 и так далее. Могу я как-то настроить валидацию так, чтобы ни один из этих диапазонов не пересекался друг с другом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Создаем отдельный метод для валидации
2. Получаем все записи из таблицы (кеша) в массив
3. Форичем проходим массив и проверяем, если from попадает в
   диапазон или to попадает в диапазон, то выходим из цикла с ошибкой
4. Если данные прошли валидацию, пишем в БД и обновляем кеш.

   ```
   public function validateInterval($attribute, $params): bool
   {
       $intervals = Model::findAll(); // тут лучше брать из кеша

       foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
           if (($this->from >= $interval['from'] && $this->from <= $interval['to']) || ($this->to >= $interval['from'] && $this->to <= $interval['to'])) {
               return false;
           }
       }

       return true;
   }
   ```

Comment: В итоге сам дошел примерно до такого варианта, но все равно спасибо. Помечу ответ как принятый.

Answer (score 1):

Можешь, но мне кажется это лучше всего делать через запрос в базу.

Я предполагаю, что в модели стоят поля value_from и value_to.
Запрос на проверку диапазонов можно сделать следующим методом:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName 
WHERE :value_from >= value_from and :value_from <= value_to -- проверяем чтобы значение не было в пределах существующего диапазона
    or :value_to >= value_from and :value_to <= value_to
    or :value_from < value_from and :value_to > value_to;  -- проверяем чтобы диапазон не обхватывал существующий диапазон
```

Где `:value_from` и `:value_to` - новые значения, которые возвращаются в форме.

Вызвать такую валидацию можно через custom function validation

```
public function rules() {
    return [
        ...
        [['value_from'], 'checkRange']
    ];
}

public function checkRange() {
    $q = self::find()->where( ... conditions here ...)->one();
    if(!empty($q)){
        $this->addError('something', 'something');
    }
}
```